# Trying to get a page to populate data from a database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to write a script that gets data from a sql server based on the id of the entry in my data base. when I try to access the page using the link with the `id` of the entry it returns as if it does not recognize the id. Below is the php code :

```
<?php
    require('includes/config.inc.php');
    require_once(MYSQL);
    $aid = FALSE;
    if (isset($_GET['aid']) && filter_var($_GET['aid'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array('min_range' => 1)) ) {
          $aid = $_GET['aid'];
          $q = "SELECT aircraft_id, aircraft_name AS name, aircraft_type AS type, tail_number AS tn FROM aircraft USING(aircraft_id) WHERE aircraft_id = $aid";
          $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
          if (!(mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0)) {
            $aid = FALSE;
          }
    }// end isset tid

    if ($aid) {
        while ($acdata = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            echo'<h2>'. $acdata['tail_number'] .'</h2>';
        }
    } else {
      echo '<p>This pages was accessed in error.</p>';
    }
?>
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Try to `var_dump($q);` before `$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);` to inspect your query and then just execute it through phphmyadmin or in MySQL server terminal directly and see what does it return.

**Update:**

Use `var_dump($q);die();` to stop script from executing after dumping.

Comment: Is it supposed to output something, becasue it just gives me the same error.

Comment: what does it mean `nothing`? Your script must stop and give you a SQL query.

Comment: That did not happen, it just gave me the error This pages was accessed in error.

Comment: Its the error that is attached to the else statment "This pages was accessed in error."

Comment: So your error is in code, not in SQL? It means that program flow doesn't "go" in your first `if (isset($_GET['aid']) && ...` statement. If code goes there it would give you SQL query. Make it get there.

Comment: Well i wrote this from what i found in a book then modifed it to fit my needs. Im not sure where i went wrong?

Comment: Your first `if (isset($_GET['aid']) && filter_var($_GET['aid'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array('min_range' => 1)) )` doesn't return `true`. That's why your code doesn't work. Check every part of that `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a field alias in your query, so you must use that in your echo to:

```
echo'<h2>'. $acdata['tn'] .'</h2>';
```

Comment: No that was not it, i get this error "This pages was accessed in error." regardless of what the $acdata tag was

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `USING(aircraft_id)`, it causes an error and your query doesn't execute.

```
"SELECT aircraft_id, aircraft_name AS name, aircraft_type AS type, tail_number AS tn FROM aircraft WHERE aircraft_id = $aid"
```

I guess it's a leftover from a previous version of the query? `Using (id)` is a shortcut for

```
FROM
foo
INNER JOIN bar ON foo.id = bar.id
```

It can be used when the tables to be joined are joined on columns which have the same name. Just shorter to write.

Since you are not joining you have to remove it.